# Page not loading in tablayout ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I created a simple tab layout application in ionic framework. I created a Extra tab and tried exactly as other tabs are implemented. But when i tried

Everything was a same as other tabs! What was i missing here?

```
My app.module.ts is:

import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/lists/lists';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here ListPage is extra class i created! I am very new to this!

TabsPage is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../lists/lists';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = ContactPage;
  tab4Root = ListPage;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

And lists.ts file is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-lists',
  templateUrl: 'lists.html'
})
export class ListPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No specific errors in console...

Answer (score 0):

Please check your tabs.html. It should be like:

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab  [root]="tab1Root"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab  [root]="tab2Root"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```